# IAMVideoProcAmp - get property that is set in auto mode

Tags: windows, video, webcam, directshow, webcam-capture

I am using DirectShow api to capture video from the web camera and I am setting various properties by using `IAMVideoProcAmp` interface (e.g. `VideoProcAmp_WhiteBalance`). 
Is it possible to get current property value which is set in auto mode? I would like to get it and apply it for manual mode.

The problem is when I try to get value in auto mode by calling [`IAMVideoProcAmp::Get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376034) method, it returns the last value that I set for manual mode (not current value, as I expect).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it works the way you want. You can read back only the values you set or can set on your own. The interface/methods are not supposed to read back the value the hardware chose itself for "automatic" mode. Eventually it depends on implementation and depends on how this is handled by the driver, but if it does not return it (because it does not have to), then you're out of luck.

Comment: It is pity. Thanks for reply. Do you know any other way how to implement it?